# Countries Additional Data Tokens not working

Tags: 7, path-aliases, tokens

I'm using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) and [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) to build path aliases that reflect the country and corresponding continent of a node. For example if a node's country field is set to Spain the url should be:
`europe/spain/node-title`.

My pattern is:
 `[node:field-prgm-country:continent-name]/[node:field-prgm-country]/[node:title]`
The country renders correctly but the continent shows nothing. I've tried any other additional data (see attached image) and none of it shows.

How do access this additional country data for use in my path aliases?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It apperas to be a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries/issues/3023824#comment-12914492) with some of the country metadata so the current solution is to use the following slightly different continent token:[node:field-prgm-country:continent]/[node:field-prgm-country]/[node:title]

Comment: Can you add some explanation about your answer?